# Using Triggers in SQL Server to keep a history

Tags: sql-server, triggers

I am using SQL Server 2012

I have a table called `AMOUNTS` and a table called `AMOUNTS_HIST`

Both tables have identical columns:

1. CHANGE_DATE
2. AMOUNT
3. COMPANY_ID
4. EXP_ID
5. SPOT
6. UPDATE_DATE [system date]

The Primary Key of `AMOUNTS` is COMPANY_ID and EXP_ID. 
The Primary Key pf `AMOUNTS_HIST` is COMPANY_ID, EXP_ID and CHANGE_DATE

Whenever I add a row in the `AMOUNTS` table, I would like to create a copy of it in the `AMOUNTS_HIST` table. [Theoretically, each time a row is added to 'AMOUNTS', the COMPANY_ID, EXP_ID, CHANGE_DATE will be unique. Practically, if they are not, the relevant row in AMOUNTS_HIST would need to be overridden. The code below does not take the overriding into account.]

I created a trigger as follows:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [MYDB].[update_history] ON [MYDB].[AMOUNTS]
FOR UPDATE
AS
INSERT MYDB.AMOUNTS_HIST (
    CHANGE_DATE,
    COMPANY_ID,
    EXP_ID,
    SPOT
    UPDATE_DATE
    )
SELECT e.CHANGE_DATE,
    e.COMPANY_ID,
    e.EXP_ID
    e.REMARKS,
    e.SPOT,
    e.UPDATE_DATE
FROM MYDB.AMOUNTS e
JOIN inserted ON inserted.company_id = e.company_id
    AND inserted.exp_id=e.exp_id
```

I don't understand why it does nothing at all in my `AMOUNTS_HIST` table.
Can anyone help?

Thanks,

Comment: This is an `UPDATE` trigger. From your description, it sounds like you want an `INSERT` trigger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just wanted to chime in.  Have you looked at CDC (change data capture).

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522489(v=sql.105).aspx
"Change data capture is designed to capture insert, update, and delete activity applied to SQL Server tables, and to make the details of the changes available in an easily consumed relational format. The change tables used by change data capture contain columns that mirror the column structure of a tracked source table, along with the metadata needed to understand the changes that have occurred.

Change data capture is available only on the Enterprise, Developer, and Evaluation editions of SQL Server."

As far as your trigger goes, when you update [MYDB].[AMOUNTS] does the trigger throw any errors?

Also I believe you can get all your data from Inserted table without needed to do the join back to mydb.amounts.

Comment: Thanks! I did consider CDC, but when I read that the default is "three days of data is retained" I assumed that it would not be suitable for my purposes, when I need the changes to be stored indefinitely. Even though I am sure one can increase the three day parameter to something else, I assumed that the whole essence of CDC is not for permanent storage of history. Am I wrong?

Comment: I think the problem with my trigger is that it was throwing errors. It was trying to put null values in a field that didn't accept null values. After I fixed this, I am now getting two rows instead of none!

Comment: Thank you for your last comment. I replaced the last 3 lines to `FROM inserted e` and it works the same!

Comment: For the CDC, you can change the default on how long the data is stored.  So you would read from the cdc created table and save to history table.  Some benefits to this, so that you can batch data.  Also CDC uses the transaction log.  So the insert transaction on [MYDB].[AMOUNTS] doesn't have to wait until you insert into MYDB.AMOUNTS_HIST.

Answer (score 2):

Probably because the trigger, the way it's currently written, will only get fired when an Update is done, not an insert.

Try changing it to:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [MYDB].[update_history] ON [MYDB].[AMOUNTS]
FOR UPDATE, INSERT
```

Comment: Thank you. This seems logical. However now that I realized that my trigger was throwing errors [see above], and I fixed it, it now works even though it is still only triggered on UPDATE. [and in fact it works too well by creating two records...]

Comment: you can avoid duplicate record creation by putting a unique index on the history table based on id of the parent and timestamp or any other field which will make it unique